# What is delayed column generation?

Tags: column-generation

I came across the term "Delayed Column Generation" yesterday and am wondering how this differs from classic Column Generation, or whether the terms are used synonymously.

Comment: I've also come across the term, and I believe they are synonyms. From a quick google search, Delayed column generation doesn't seem to be different.

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge, originally "column generation" meant "adding columns to the simplex tableau by inspection of available variables which are all explicitly available." This was a special implementation of the simplex algorithm to deal with the limited memory in old computers. "Delayed column generation" means that not all variables (columns) are available from the start and their generation is delayed. The original column generation approach is probably not used at all nowadays, so people use the term "column generation" as a shortcut for "delayed column generation".